# Windows Explorer appears in Windows 10 volume control

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, volume-mixer

I'm a new user of Windows 10. My sound mixer (volume control) used to look like this:

[image: only System Sounds]

But today it looks like this:

[image: Windows Explorer appears]

Why is the Windows Explorer entry there? Is it normal, and does it do anything helpful?

Additional info:

- I have Windows 10 x64
- I ran scans with Windows Defender and Kaspersky; nothing bad was found
- The slider for Windows Explorer doesn't appear to have any effect

Answer (score 0):

Windows Explorer can make "navigation click" sounds. These will cause Windows Explorer to appear in the sound mixer window. These sounds may have been enabled and then disabled (or there may be other sounds that Explorer makes that I am not familiar with). If you do not hear any sounds from Explorer, then there is nothing to worry about. Otherwise, poke around in the control panel (something like Sound->Sounds).

Comment: I already have my sound scheme disabled, and I checked the "start navigation" tab and it's off, it always was, nothing was changed here to cause the "windows explorer" icon to appear in volume mixer also I don't hear any sounds. But I guess Im more calm now, originally I thought it was a malware/virus.

Comment: Have you done a reboot? Might need a reboot to clear it out of the mixer. Failing that, I haven't a clue...

Comment: Did that, it dissapears after the reboot, but it reapers after a while for some reason, I only have skype and chrome open so I don't think it's because of that. Maybe this is normal? No idea...?